# Why can I not use "ini_get()" or "ini_get_all()"?

Tags: php

I  use `ini_get('tmp_dir')` but it returns false.
I found out I can't use `ini_get()` and `ini_get_all()` on server. 
Why can I not use it?

Comment: What do you need it for in the first place? Also, define "can't use". Are you getting an error message when calling them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, as others already say, the hosting provider is blocking scripts from calling the `ini_get()` function for security reasons.

In this case, however, I would not use the system's temporary directory at all. Chances are that your script can't write or read there either, also for security reasons.

If you need to create temporary files, best use a directory inside your user directory (but outside the web root).

Comment: yes, i cany use tmp , then i use  a directory inside my directory , too

Answer (score 1):

It might be a limitation of your hosting service. You should try to contact them.

Answer (score 0):

use this function:

[sys_get_temp_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php)

Returns the path of the directory PHP stores temporary files in by default

Answer (score 0):

It can be disabled by [`disable_functions`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) directive, which is quite usually the case on virtual hosting services for security reasons.